# how to update object when passed to another controller in javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

hey so i have a GUI the use case is that upon clicking a button a new window opens which contains text fields of the attributes of the object passed to that window now the user clicks a button in the new window and the object attributes should be updated with the values of that are in the text fields.

lets say we have a window lets say main window which has a button upon clicking this function this code runs

```
public void openwindow(){

    FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("subWindow.fxml"));
            Stage stage=new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);

            stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));

            ParameterssubWindowController controller=  loader.<ParameterssubWindowController>getController();

            controller.initData(A);

            stage.show();

}
```

this function opens a subwindow and runs the function initData() that is present in the subwindow controller, to this we have passed an object `A of the class

```
public class Dog {

public double height=2;
public double weight=3;

}
```

the subwindow contains 2 text fields called height and weight so upon opening the two textfields will display the default height and weight of A
so the user can change these values and click update button to update the values of A height and weight.

subWindowController

```
   import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

    /**
     *
     * @author akhil kumar
     */
    public class ParametersCatchmentController {

        @FXML
        private TextField weight;
        @FXML
        private TextField height;



        public void initData(Dog A){

            weight.setText(String.valueOf(A.weight));
            height.setText(String.valueOf(A.height));


        }


        public void update(){
           /** this function is linked to the update button upon clicking this 
               A.height=Double.parseDouble(height.getText());
               A.weight=Double.parseDouble(weight.getText());
              but since A is a local parameter of initData not able to access A in update to change the values 
           ** /
         }
    }
```

update() function is linked to the update button upon clicking this

```
A.height=Double.parseDouble(height.getText());
           A.weight=Double.parseDouble(weight.getText());
```

but since A is a local parameter of initData i am not able to use it in the fucntion update()

so upon closing the subwindow the object A should have the new values given by the user so if he gave 4 and 5 respectively then A.height=4 and A.weight = 5

how do i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the object that's passed to the method to an instance field, so that you can access it later:

```
public class ParametersCatchmentController {

    @FXML
    private TextField weight;
    @FXML
    private TextField height;

    private Dog a ;

    public void initData(Dog a){

        weight.setText(String.valueOf(a.weight));
        height.setText(String.valueOf(a.height));

        this.a = a ;
    }


    public void update(){
       a.height=Double.parseDouble(height.getText());
       a.weight=Double.parseDouble(weight.getText());
    }
}
```